# Criar módulos utilizando Unity (IoC)

Tags: c#, .net, injeção-de-dependência, ddd

Em uma aplicação utilizando uma arquitetura de multicamadas (n-layer), temos a camada de infraestrutura onde utilizamos um container IoC para registrar as dependências necessárias. Em um protótipo que estou trabalhando, estou utilizando o Unity Application Block [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) como container. Como será um projeto que poderá crescer, gostaria de poder separar as dependências por módulos. Sei que no [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) é possível criar estes módulos criando uma classe herdando de NinjectModule e sobrescrevendo o método Load. Após a criação destes módulos é possível carregá-los quando necessário (um ou mais módulos)

Alguém saberia me dizer se no Unity existe algo semelhante? Se existir, poderiam indicar algum exemplo ou modelo?

Answer (score 2):

Sei que a pergunta é sobre Unity, mas espero ajudar mesmo assim.

[Eu tenho um projeto DDD no GitHub](https://github.com/thiagolunardi/MvcMusicStoreDDD) - já bastante datado, aliás, mas ainda válido para sua questão - onde eu tenho o injetor isolado e modularizado. Porém estou usando [SimpleInjector](https://simpleinjector.org/index.html).

Recomendo, inclusive que estude uma substituiçao, visto que [SimpleInjector é um dos mais rápidos injetores do mercado](http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison), e também muito bem recomendado. Também recomendo fortemente que evite Ninject, visto que é um dos - senão o - mais lento do mercado.

IoC:

```
public class IoC
{
    private Container _container;
    public Container Container
    {
        get
        {
            if (_container != null) return _container;

            _container = new Container();

            Register(_container, InfrastructureInjectors.GetInjectors());
            Register(_container, RepositoryInjectors.GetInjectors());
            Register(_container, ApplicationInjectors.GetInjectors());
            Register(_container, ServiceInjectors.GetInjectors());

            return _container;
        }
    }
}
```

Módulo:

```
public class InfrastructureInjectors
{
    public static Dictionary<Type, Type> GetInjectors()
    {
        return new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            {typeof (IContextManager<MainContext>), typeof (ContextManager<MainContext>)},
            {typeof (IUnitOfWork<MainContext>), typeof (UnitOfWork<MainContext>)}
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tanto quanto sei, não existe. É no entanto possível registar módulos dinamicamente, e uma solução para esse problema poderia passar por usar algo como o MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework), incluído no .NET 3.5 e superior, para encontrar classes em DLLs numa qualquer pasta ou subpasta que implementem um dado contrato (interface ou classe base abstracta).